# In iOS is the Initial View Controller always the same as the Root View Controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

In the 'Start Developing iOS Apps Today' guide by Apple it says that, "the first item added to the [navigation] stack is the Root View Controller and is never popped off the stack." Later on in the same section it goes on to say, "one of the view controllers is marked as the Initial View Controller ... this is the view controller that will be displayed the first time the app is launched."

My question is are the Initial View Controller and the Root View Controller always the same thing or can they be different? For example, if you created a game where the Root View Controller was the view where you played the game could you have a different controller (maybe the start screen) be the Initial View Controller, and how would this work?

Comment: sorry my bad please refer to @aaron's link

Comment: @thndrkiss Search "initial view controller" on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, if you created a game where the Root View Controller was
>   the view where you played the game could you have a different
>   controller (maybe the start screen) be the Initial View Controller,
>   and how would this work?

Let's say for the sake of argument that the game uses a navigation controller to manage its various view controllers. In that case, the nav controller would likely be the *initial* view controller as well as the window's *root* view controller. The game board view controller might then be the nav controller's *root* view controller.

If you wanted to show a "game start" view controller at the beginning of the game, there are at least three reasonable options:

1. Make the game start view controller the nav controller's root and *push* the game board controller onto the nav stack when the user starts the game.
2. Present the game start view controller modally, and dismiss it when the user wants to start the game.
3. Make the game start view controller the initial view controller (and the window's root view controller), and then *present* the navigation controller (with the game board view controller as it's root) modally.

So no, the "initial" view controller doesn't need to be the view controller that the user actually sees first, it's just the one that's loaded first from the storyboard. It may contain other view controllers, or it might cause some other view controller to be presented immediately.

Comment: Yeah I think that the second situation is kind of what I was imagining. Thanks, both of the answers so far are helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are two root view controllers in play here:

1. Your application's key `UIWindow`'s [`rootViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController). (Most apps only have one `UIWindow` but some have more than one.)
2. A `UINavigationController`'s root view controller (the first object in [its `viewControllers` array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers)).

The **Initial View Controller** in a storyboard will typically be set as your key window's root view controller (#1), although this too has exceptions.

If that happens to be a navigation controller (this is common), then that navigation controller will have its own root view controller (#2).

Comment: #1 could be more clear -- the app itself doesn't have a root view controller, and if there are more than one window, each one has its own `rootViewController`. It'd probably be better to just call it the window's root view controller and leave the app out of it.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the feedback. I made minor updates but didn't go into a ton of detail since I would basically be copying your answer.

Comment: Well touché. I wrote pretty much the same as you at first, had to go in a different direction after I saw yours. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The initial view controller is associated with the storyboard which does the work for you in terms of making that the root view controller of the window.

You can have further root view controllers inside your application but these are secondary and separate to the window's root view controller.