# Black screen shown after launch screen

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uiscenedelegate

I have a storyboard file that I want to use as my launch screen. I have set the ViewController in that storyboard to be the initial one.

I've also set the launch screen like so:

[image]

Here's the code I have in my `SceneDelegate` for selecting the first ViewController to show the user:

```swift
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: "Channels") as! UINavigationController
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I see the launch screen upon first starting the app, then a black screen; and then finally my user interface.

Comment: `UINavigationController` is a view controller?

Comment: I'm surprised that your app doesn't crash.

Comment: The black screen might be caused by the code you showed. Try deleting it.

Comment: Also please note that a launch screen is not a splash screen.

Comment: I don't see the problem in your code.

Comment: you need to show xcode version, run it in local device, test your view controller.

Comment: their might be one more possibility if run on dark theme and set view color as system white color it will show also black.

Comment: Please check below thread:
[getting a blank or blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207755/ios13-on-xcode-11-black-screen-even-after-adding-scenedelegate-and-updating-info/59047140#59047140)

Answer (score 2):

check if "is Initial Viewcontroller" is selected for the ViewController in your story board.
[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn3rG.png)

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  `Initial Viewcontroller` stands for `rootViewController` it's already set in code.

Comment: @jatinfl rootViewController and Initial ViewController are separate. The Initial View Controller refers to a Storyboard's initial ViewController https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252467/in-ios-is-the-initial-view-controller-always-the-same-as-the-root-view-controlle

Comment: @froggomad yeah i know that but while you set rootview controller with code it will ignore initial view controller from storyboard.

Comment: It doesn't actually get ignored, there are 2 root viewControllers in play and the Initial ViewController may be displayed briefly as it's set as the key window's rootViewController. I've seen this behavior plenty when I use the window's root view controller to display authentication screens instead of going to the storyboard's initial view controller

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have an initial view controller somewhere that doesn't have a background color. I would recommend going through your storyboard and checking to see if you have a "is Initial ViewController" boxed checked in your panel on the right.

[image: is Initial View Controller]

Comment: their might be one more possibility if run on dark theme and set view color as system white color it will show also black.

Comment: @jatinfl regardless of color style if you do not have the view controller set as the initial view controller it would still appear black.

Comment: yeah i know that's why i just comment another possibility.

Comment: Yeah; I have initial view controller set in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

After reading tons of threads online and spending many hours trying to figure this out, I found a solution for eliminating the black screen that appears between the launch screen and the main app screen (something that I didn't see anyone else mention).

It is very simple: leave out the .storyboard extension of the name of the launch screen. With this small (and illogical) change, my launch screen remains visible until it is replaced by the actual app, no more black in between.

To solve this problem, I made this change in Info.plist:

From:

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
```

To:

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

You can also make this change by editing the "Launch screen interface file base name" property value to remove the .storyboard part of the name shown there.

Comment: I am both delighted and angry to say that this IS the solution. Developing with apple is just painful and illogical. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0):

I have Structured project files and moved info.plist in "RequiredFiles" folder.

But in Build Settings info.plist path was "ProjectName/Info.plist".
I changed it to "ProjectName/RequiredFiles/Info.plist"